# Can't use Gmail and Google play store

Tags: google-play-store

In my Samsung galaxy on nxt, android version 8.1.0. in my phn I can't use Gmail as it is showing msg that Google play is updating. And same time can't sign in Google play store. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the internet connectivity. Other thing is to reboot the phone. Ideally this should help and if it doesn't you need to go to customer care of Samsung.